# A function $f\colon[a,b] \to \mathbb R$ which is $C^1$ on $(a,b)$ must be $f'$ restricted on $(a,b)$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

A function $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb R$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $C^1$ on $(a,b)$. Must its derivative $f':(a,b) \to \mathbb R$ be restricted on $(a,b)$ (i.e. $\forall x \in (a,b), |f(x)| < M \in \mathbb R$)?

Comment: What do you mean by "restricted"?

Comment: When you ask if $|f'(x)| < M$ for all $x\in(a,b)$, you are asking $f'$ is *bounded* on the interval, not *restricted* (which usually means that the domain is being shrunk).

Comment: The classic example is the upper half of the unit circle over the interval $[-1,1].$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The word you are looking for is "*bounded*" (*restricted* would typically apply to the domain of the function, and mean it is a proper subset of a larger, original domain).

And **no**, it need not be: consider $f\colon[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$.